# связи в EER диаграмме MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Делаю ERR диаграмму через MySQL Workbench, использую для языков и стран связь - многие ко многим, для континентов и стран - один ко многим(до религий ще не добрался, потому что не получается с языками). И вроде бы как должно работать, но получается если делаю запрос рода

```
SELECT country.name, partoftheworld.NamePartOfTheWorld, language.LanguageName
FROM country, partoftheworld, language
WHERE (((partoftheworld.id)="4")AND((language.id)="4"));
```

то, вне зависимости от того какие ID я поставлю, все равно выводятся названия всех стран. Хотя в таблице language_has_country явно прописано какой id языка относится к id страны. Хотелось бы понять, почему не выводится только нужная мне информация. Ниже код таблицы

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
    SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
    SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
    
    
    -- Schema world
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `world` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 ;
    USE `world` ;
    
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `world`.`partoftheworld`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `world`.`partoftheworld` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL,
      `NamePartOfTheWorld` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb3;
    
    
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `world`.`country`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `world`.`country` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL,
      `partoftheworld_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `capital` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      INDEX `fk_country_partoftheworld1_idx` (`partoftheworld_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_country_partoftheworld1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`partoftheworld_id`)
        REFERENCES `world`.`partoftheworld` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb3;
    
    
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `world`.`language`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `world`.`language` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `LanguageName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb3;
    
    
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `world`.`religion`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `world`.`religion` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `country_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `ReligionName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      INDEX `fk_religion_country1_idx` (`country_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_religion_country1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`)
        REFERENCES `world`.`country` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb3;
    
    
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `world`.`language_has_country`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `world`.`language_has_country` (
      `country_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `language_id` INT NOT NULL,
      INDEX `fk_language_has_country_country1_idx` (`country_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
      INDEX `fk_language_has_country_language1_idx` (`language_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
      PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`, `language_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_language_has_country_language1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`)
        REFERENCES `world`.`language` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_language_has_country_country1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`)
        REFERENCES `world`.`country` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb3;
    
    
    SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
    SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Отсутствуют условия связывания. Используйте нормальный JOIN, а не запятую.